# Input/output device issues in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, usb, keyboard, bluetooth, intel

Edit: Noted later in post but I've tested in 20.04 with similar results. If post needs to be removed then go for it.

I have a few hardware issues that I believe might be related? I recently moved a drive with Ubuntu 21.04 (GNOME 3.38.5 and X11) from an HP 8300 to an Intel NUC 11 NUC11PAHi7.  .

1. I have a dummy HDMI that when plugged in directly to HDMI port nothing happens (No display just a black screen). I’ve looked at the log file and nothing is registered when I plug and unplug the dummy.

   - When I plug in the same dummy HDMI via HDMI to USB-C adapter the adapter shows up in the logs but not the HDMI
   - When I plug in the dummy HDMI via a USB-C hub (7 in 1) everything works fine.
2. If I disconnect HDMI from my machine while booted the system will lock up within 12 hours of the disconnect (It honestly seems quicker maybe 2-6 hours but the first time I noticed this was overnight after I’d gone to bed so I’ll assume it ran for a while)

   - I can start with HDMI connected or connect my monitor after boot with no issues, but if I disconnect after either of these events my computer becomes unresponsive

     1. The system runs headless so I usually SSH in or use VNC (hence the dummy HDMI). However, after I’ve disconnected HDMI (the dummy or an actual HDMI connected to a monitor) my system loses connection to the internet sometime in the 12 hour window (no access to HomeAssistant, SSH or VNC).
     2. At this point I can only assume the entire system locks up. I haven't been able to diagnose this any further because re-connecting an HDMI at this point in the process yields a “No Signal” from my monitor. The only methods I know to get everything back up is a hard restart or Ctrl+Print Screen+REISUB
   - When logged in via VNC I’ve noticed that after disconnecting the HDMI the screen doesn’t go back to a black screen. A couple of the icons move and the GUI just hangs.
3. If, while my system is booted, I connect a new device (USB and HDMI tested so far) my keyboard(Bluetooth dongle connected via USB-C hub) becomes laggy (every other input received or ~2-6 keystrokes delayed) at best and in most cases completely unresponsive.

   - The keyboard suffers the same issue when connected directly in USB ports from boot no matter what.
   - The mouse (also Bluetooth) is a bit jumpy when connected directly via USB as well.

The results seemed the same when booting from an Ubuntu 20.04LTS install USB under the “Try Ubuntu” Option although I admittedly didn’t test as extensively. It haven't been able to reproduce the display problem on another OS as all the other computers I have access to (Windows and Mac) can run headless without needing a display attached. Running windows from an SSD in the same NUC had no I/O issues. I haven’t tried new drivers yet as everything works via USB-C and I’ll try wired keyboard/mouse tomorrow when I can borrow some. The system lock up thing has thrown me. I can post logs or screenshots but I’m not sure where to start/what would be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades   *Do note: you may not need to follow EOLUpgrades advice yet as noted in the EOL annoucement*

Comment: I noted later in post, but I tested in 20.04LTS as well. Changed title and noted the edit.

Comment: The system does not lock up, no. Instead it shuts down because there is no display. This is a power-saving "feature" that is built into the BIOS/UEFI of many NUCs. The systems will run for a set period of time (usually 4 hours for HP, 8 for Lenovo, etc.) then shut down. The logs should confirm this. You will probably need to check your BIOS/UEFI for a "Headless Mode" and ensure it's enabled. Once it is, the dummy HDMI plug will no longer be required.

Comment: I'll definitely take a look at my BIOS options, but shouldn't the power save function the same even when no display is detected? Also the power button stays on and I can still hear activity from the machine. As far as logs, what should I be looking for/where? Thanks again

Comment: _I've tested on 20.04_ So, you're running 20.04 now? If not then your question is still off-topic. But assuming you're now using 20.04 I'm voting to leave this question open (on-topic).