# Monitor won't display after disconnecting and reconnecting

Tags: display, vnc

Ubuntu 22.04 fresh install.
Everything initially appeared to be working OK. I was able to use remote desktop using TightVNC but then I noticed VNC wouldn't reconnect if the screen blanked. Worse, if I disconnected the monitor for any length of time and then reconnected it, there is no display on the monitor. I can still log in via SSH but I would like to be able to use VNC without having a monitor permanently connected.

Comment: Are you sure it's the screen blanker, rather than the whole system going to sleep?

Comment: With the monitor connected I VNC connects. I noticed after a while, the VNC connection dropped and as far as I can tell, it coincides with the screen blanking. I can still SSH ok. Moving the mouse (on the server) turns the display back on and then VNC will connect again.
After disconnecting the display, I can still SSH and everything else (web,ftp etc.) is still there so the system has definitely not gone into sleep mode.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is an old issue e.g.:

[How to use Ubuntu 18.04 on VNC without display attached?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033436/how-to-use-ubuntu-18-04-on-vnc-without-display-attached)

[Input/output device issues in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1388890/input-output-device-issues-in-ubuntu-20-04)

There are partial workarounds involving the creation of a dummy monitor but if you want to swap between using a physical monitor and VNC, you will likely run into the problem where the monitor just displays a blank screen with a cursor top left.

The only reliable solution appears to be to use a dummy HDMI e.g. https://thepihut.com/products/hdmi-dummy-plug.

A hardware workaround for a software bug. Got to be a first.